# Can I typedef unnamed struct/class in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, typedef

In C, I can typedef unnamed (no tag) struct:

```
typedef struct {
 int val;
} Foo_t;
```

But when I tried to do the same in c++:

```
typedef struct
{
    A(int a) : a_var(a) {}
    int a_var;
} A;

typedef struct : public A
{
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b_var(b) {}
    int b_var;
} B;

B &getB()
{
    static B b(1, 2);
    return b;
}
int main() {}
```

*output*:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘A’ with no type
error: only constructors take member initializers
error: class ‘<unnamed struct>’ does not have any field named ‘A’
```

I know I am using constructor `A(int a)` of "unnamed" struct, but right after it, it is `typedef`ed. So constructors are only available to know types

Comment: Your title question does not match the implied question in the exposition.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for example with this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct
{
    A(int a) : a_var(a) {}
    int a_var;
} A;
```

is that within the unnamed structure there is used undeclared name A as a name of a constructor. So this declaration is invalid.

By the way the same problem exists else in C.

Consider for example a typedef declaration of a structure used to define a node of a linked list.

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    A *next;
} A;
```

Again the name `A` within the structure definition is undefined.

Even if you will write like

```
typedef struct A
{
    int data;
    A *next;
} A;
```

nevertheless the name `A` is still undeclared within the structure in C. You have to write in C

```
typedef struct A
{
    int data;
    struct A *next;
} A;
```

On the other hand, in C++ such a typedef declaration is valid.

Comment: I mentioned it in my post (at the end - the constructors are only available to know types), but that breaks the compatibility to C (except - of course - c structs have no constructors)

Comment: @milanHrabos the point is that are not "doing the same in C++" in your example

Comment: @idclev463035818 the only way to enable unknow types is via pointers (which are know, their size), but I am not able to make function pointer constructor in `c++` e.g. `(*A)(int)` in order to make the constructor to unknonw type possible. C++ should add this feature to remain the compatibility with C

Comment: @milanHrabos I dont really understand. Can you provide an example where compatibility is broken? Your example is C++, so C compatibility isnt an issue

Comment: @idclev463035818 you said `A is undefined`, and you are right. That type is not know, so the only possible (and in `C` available) solution is to use pointer for that type `A*`. But that typed is used in *construction* where you **cannot** use a pointer (e.g make it function pointer), whereas in `C` you can (for ordinary functions of course, C has no constructions). That is the situation, where compatibility is broken

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but it's not possible to make use of the type name inside the structure, as you said.

```
// this is valid
typedef struct{
   int x;
   void set(int n){x=n;}
} A;

// this is not
typedef struct{
    int x;
    B(int n){x = n;}
} B;

// you can only have constructor with named structs
typedef struct st_C{
    int x;
    st_C(int n){x = n;}
} C;

// this is valid
C *foo = new C(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you often have to write typdefs like this:

```
typedef struct {
 int val;
} Foo_t;
```

to avoid having to write

```
struct Foo_t f;
```

every time, which soon becomes quite tedious.

In C++, all `struct`s `union`s and `enum`s declarations act as though they are *implicitly* `typedef`ed. So you can declare a struct like this:

```
struct A
{
    A(int a) : a_var(a) {}
    int a_var;
};
```

However, structs in C++ are often aggregates (a simple collection of data), and you don't need the constructors. So the following is fine:

```
struct A
{
    int a_var;
    int b_var;
};
```

The constructor is implicitly defined by the compiler, and when you use *value initialisation* with braces:

```
A a{};
```

all the members of the struct will be zeroed out.